# Application for allowing a user to "follow" another user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have taken a stab at creating my first jQuery script from scratch. I use this to post an update to a Django application that allows a user to "follow" another user. I am sure that there are better ways to do this and I appreciate any help that anyone can give.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.follow').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        var followtype = jQuery(this).text();
        var user = jQuery(".follow").attr("href").match('/relationships/[a-z]+/([a-z]+)/following/')[1];
        var postdata = {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        }
        jQuery.post(url, postdata, function(json){
            if(json.result == '1') {
                if(followtype == 'Follow') {
                    jQuery('.follow').text('Unfollow');
                    jQuery('.follow').attr("href", '/relationships/remove/'+user+'/following/');
                } else {
                    jQuery('.follow').text('Follow');
                    jQuery('.follow').attr("href", '/relationships/add/'+user+'/following/');
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it. There may be flaws because you haven't provided your HTML.

I assume that within the `click` handler, you only want to interact with the current element being clicked. The reason I say that is because you had `$('.follow')` a number of times in there, which would affect *all* `.follow` elements.

```
         //     v--- makes the shortcut available inside the .ready() callback
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.follow').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

            // assuming it's a link, no need for jQuery here
        var url = this.href;

            // Looking at the code in your callback, I assume you only have text content
        var followtype = this.innerHTML;

            // I assume you actually want just the current "follow", not all
        var user = url.match('/relationships/[a-z]+/([a-z]+)/following/');

            // Make certain there was a match before accessing the Array.
            // If there was no match, just return the function
        if( user )
            user = user[1];
        else
            return;

        var postdata = {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        };
            // Inside the $.post callback, are we still only working with the current
            //   "follow" clicked? If so, cache it here, and use it in the callback
        var this_follow = this;

        $.post(url, postdata, function(json){
            if(json.result == '1') {
                if(followtype == 'Follow') {
                     this_follow.innerHTML = 'Unfollow';
                     this_follow.pathname = '/relationships/remove/'+user+'/following/';
                } else {
                    this_follow.innerHTML = 'Follow';
                    this_follow.pathname = '/relationships/add/'+user+'/following/';
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

As you can see, I tend to eliminate jQuery when convenient.

I should note that using `.innerHTML` in the way I have is cheating a bit. It's an HTML parser really, but it's convenient for changing small chunks of text quickly.

To do it properly, you'd select the child text node of the element, and change its `nodeValue`.

```
this_follow.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Unfollow';
```

Answer (score 2):

Two generic notes:

1. I'd invert the condition:

   ```
   jQuery.post(url, postdata, function(json){
       if(json.result != '1') {
           return;
       }
       if(followtype == 'Follow') {
           jQuery('.follow').text('Unfollow');
           jQuery('.follow').attr("href", '/relationships/remove/'+user+'/following/');
       } else {
           jQuery('.follow').text('Follow');
           jQuery('.follow').attr("href", '/relationships/add/'+user+'/following/');
       }
   }
   ```

   It makes the code flatten and more readable.

   References: *Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*; [Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)
2. Lots of duplication could be eliminated with local variables:

   ```
       var text;
       var command;
       if (followtype == 'Follow') {
           text = 'Unfollow';
           command = 'remove';
       } else {
           text = 'Follow';
           command = 'add';
       }
       var follow = jQuery('.follow');
       follow.text(text);
       follow.attr("href", '/relationships/' + command + '/' + user + '/following/');
   ```